# Static IP address from DHCP server through a network repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, repeater

My DHCP server is on a [Zyxel VMG8825-B50B](https://www.zyxel.com/products_services/Multy-Pro-AC2400-VDSL2-Combo-WAN-Gigabit-IAD-VMG8825-B-Series/) router which is able to manage static IP address based on devices MAC addresses.

This year I introduced in my network a [FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 1160](https://en.avm.de/press/press-releases/2016/02/new-fritzwlan-repeater-1160-fast-wireless-lan-for-all-mobile-devices-in-the-home-network/), which honestly works fine as repeater. It gets from DHCP his own IP address and works transparently towards the devices, presenting the same SSID of the router, so once plugged no further configuration is necessary.

My problems begun when I needed to reserve the IP addresses of some Laptops. Typically I manage this case by configuring on the router the MAC addresses and the corresponding IP addresses, and this works when a Laptop is directly connected to the router. When a Laptop is in the repeater area, its MAC address is replaced by the repeater with 2 dummy MAC addresses (for 2.4 GHz and for 5 GHz interfaces), and the DHCP ignores dummy MAC address in its configuration.

As example:

```
Laptop near the router
    -> The router sees B0-48-7A-E6-49-E5 MAC Address
    -> The DHCP applies the rule and the Laptop gets the fixed IP Address

Laptop near the repeater
    -> The router sees 9E:FF:4D:83:FA:DD (2.4 GHz) and A0:AF:BD:E4:78:F7 (5 GHz)
    -> The DHCP doesn't applies the rule and the Laptop gets a dynamic IP Address (*)
```

(*) In fact, it takes two IP Addresses, and dynamically switch on one or on the other depending on network traffic because the Wi-Fi interface automatically switches on 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz adapter.

How could i solve the issue?

- I could exclude a range of addresses from the DHCP and set them manually on the desktop devices, but I don't find it practical to have manual addresses on the laptops, I would like that at least these be managed by the DHCP.
- The router manages 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz as one interface. I could use two different SSIDs and see if the repeater keeps for the laptops the assigned address, but since there is interference from other devices, it is convenient to take advantage of the dual band.

Comment: Can your DHCP server use the Client-ID instead of the raw MAC address?

Comment: Basing on the user manual, the use of the Client ID is supported, but my router is branded and I'm not sure that this option is available. This evening I will take a look, thank you for the hint.